# Are there supposed to be multiple container divs in a Twitter Bootstrap site?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to apply a Bootstrap theme I purchased to a Rails application I have. The layout seems to be pretty complex, with multiple containers, some of them inside navbars. I don't understand it at all. I want to make sure this layout is the right way to do things, and not trust that it's correct just because I bought it.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="span2">

  <!-- Top navigation bar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="menu" href="/item1">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu" href="/item2">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu" href="/item3">Item3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>  
          </ul> <!-- nav -->
        </div><!-- nav-collapse -->
      </div> <!-- container -->
    </div> <!-- navbar-inner -->
  </div> <!-- navbar -->
</div> <!-- span2 -->

<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span9">
      <!-- stuff -->
    </div> <!-- span9 -->
  </div> <!-- row-fluid -->

  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="footer span12">
      <div class="well">
        <footer>
          &copy; MyCompany, LLC 2013
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /span12 -->
  </div> <!-- row-fluid -->

</div> <!-- container-fluid -->
```

This just seems weird.

- First of all I thought I had 12 columns to work with, but 9 + 2 above only equals 11.
- Second, the `span9` and the `span2` are at different levels.
- Third, Don't I have to establish a grid with a `container` before I set a `spanN` div? The first `span2` is just hanging in space.

If I had to distill this down, I guess my main question would be: What is the main purpose of a container in Twitter Bootstrap? I can't seem to find the answer to that one question via Google or the Bootstrap docs. Knowing that would probably help me determine whether it makes sense to have more than one container. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: first question... does it work? is there anything untoward or not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap has alot of pre written CSS you can use by calling its class in html. If you take a look at some of the examples that is on the twitter bootstrap page you can see that all the div are there for a reason. Disregard the unconventional html labeling when you are using twitter bootstrap defined classes.

If you take a look at the layout tutorial

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

it explains how to nest columns to position your divs which requires multiple divs

The nav tutorial is here

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

To answer your container question.

Fixed layout
Provides a common fixed-width (and optionally responsive) layout with only

```
<div class="container"> required.
```

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts

hope it helps